# How can I connect to the apollo graphql-websocket in another programming language?

Tags: python, graphql, apollostack, graphql-subscriptions

Currently I am looking into GraphQL Server from Apollo, to replace our current Java implementation. As we also might want to use subscriptions, I try to get some simple server-client proof of concept up and running. I got the subscription part working using the GitHunt example.

As I don't really need or want a UI. For now, I want a simple client to just receive the notifications from the subscription interface. As fas as I could see, this is Websocket. Knowing that, I created a Python script that opens a [websocket](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) to the specified host and port (ws://localhost:8090). This results in a [bad handshake error](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/blob/master/websocket/_exceptions.py).

What way can I go forward? Did someone already create a client, other than the apollo-client? And if so; how do you create the websocket?

Answer (score 0):

I might try using a headless browser like, slimmer js, It supports websockets.
https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs.

I'm wondering if there is something the python interface just isn't handling that slimer js would be. I'm no websocket expert, so just my 2 cents :)

Comment: The 'annoying' part here, is that I can just use the existing [Apollostack Subscription Transport WS](https://github.com/apollostack/subscriptions-transport-ws) package to make it work in i.e. a headless browser. That still doesn't allow me to use it in any other way.
However - I will have a look in SlimerJS and see if it can quickly prove my proof of concept. Thanks!

Comment: I did some further analysis using wireshark and it seems that the Subscriptions GraphQL request triggers one or two WebSockets which are handshaked using generated server-client keys. After some hours trying to get it working, I gave up :) Thanks for asking!